# How to increment column ordinal position in a while function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Abstract:**  I have a table with multiple columns and I am trying to implement a while (loop) function to all the columns to pull out the average of each column.

I **coded** this to attribute a number to each column (to ease the possibility of an incremental method)

```
Declare @tablename as varchar(128)
Declare @column1 as varchar(128)
Delect @tablename = 'MOMENTUM_Results'

Select @column1 = sc.name
from sysobjects as so inner join syscolumns as sc on so.id = sc.id 
where so.name = @tablename and sc.colid = 2
```

*When I print this code it prints the name of the column based on the number I put from 1 to 122.*

**Code for the loop function:**

```
WHILE ....
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' + @column1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @column1 + '] = 1'
END
```

But I definitely do not have a clue how to integrate this function into the loop so the function goes through all the columns one by one,  therefore looking for some advice..

Thank you!

R.H.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many rows are there? Is performance relevant?

Comment: 1300 rows.. and performance may not be relevant

Comment: Furthermore: Do you need this fully generically or do you know the column names in advance?

Comment: I know the column names in advance, I just did it to ease the way I would loop through each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just move your `SELECT` from `sys.Columns` into the body of your `WHILE` loop to get the one you're after? Something like this...

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @COUNTER INT;
SET @TABLENAME = 'MOMENTUM_Results';
SET @COUNTER = 1;

WHILE ....
BEGIN

    SELECT @COLUMN1 = C.Name
    FROM sys.Columns C
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = @TABLENAME 
    AND C.column_id = @COUNTER
    ;
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' + @COLUMN1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
    Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @COLUMN1 + '] = 1';

    ... Other Stuff ...

    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;

END
;
```

Maybe I didn't properly understand your question, but if you already have everything written out you could just change the placement to select the column names you want.

Of course you can also add additional conditions to make sure you're getting matched columns, or columns by name, or whatever...

**EDIT:**

You asked about inserting the resultant query into a table.  If you already have a table with a column ready to receive the query, then the answer is simple... In the body of your `WHILE` loop, after retrieving the desired query, simply add an `INSERT` command:

```
WHILE ....
BEGIN

    SELECT @COLUMN1 = C.Name
    FROM sys.Columns C
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = @TABLENAME 
    AND C.column_id = @COUNTER
    ;
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' + @COLUMN1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
    Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @COLUMN1 + '] = 1';

    INSERT INTO <mytable> (<querycolumn>) VALUES (@SQL);
    ... Other Stuff ...

    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;
```

If you need to create the table, you can do that in the head of the script, before declaring anything else, and do the same thing during the `WHILE`:

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @COUNTER INT;
SET @TABLENAME = 'MOMENTUM_Results';
SET @COUNTER = 1;
CREATE TABLE <mytable> (<optional_column1>,<optional_column2>,<querycolumn>);

....

WHILE ....
BEGIN

    SELECT @COLUMN1 = C.Name
    FROM sys.Columns C
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = @TABLENAME 
    AND C.column_id = @COUNTER
    ;
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' + @COLUMN1 + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
    Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @COLUMN1 + '] = 1';

    INSERT INTO <mytable> (<querycolumn>) VALUES (@SQL);
    ... Other Stuff ...

    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;
```

Comment: When I print it works but when I execute it sends me this:                                                                The name 'SELECT AVG(MR.[2006-12-30]) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
    Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Hey there! Any chance you can show me the printed string that's returned (just one example should be okay) so I can make sure I know what the problem is?

Comment: SELECT AVG(MR.[2006-12-30]) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
    Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.

Comment: I added to the post, the print result

Comment: @RobinhoHcp Is the `@SQL` parameter an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable, or is it limited?

Comment: it's a VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: it worked ! I had to put brackets in the execute (@SQL).. thanks  @3BK !

Comment: By the way would you know how can I insert the result query into a table? thanks @3BK

Comment: permanent ! Since I will compute the top quintile average and bottom quintile average and hopefully create a table with 2 rows and the 121 columns..

Comment: Edited my answer to provide you with a solution for that, too.  Let me know if there are more problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136882/discussion-between-robin-hcp-and-3bk).

Comment: Hey are you there @3BK ?

Answer (score 1):

1. First get all the column names in that table into a temporary table(#temp)
2. Get the count of all columns(@count_of_columns) in that temptable.
3. declare a variable @count=1
4. Declare while loop as While(@count<=@count_of_columns)

--> fetch the column name one after another inside this while loop using the following query

```
SET @column1=(select top 1 column1 from 
(select Row_number()over (order by column1) as r_n_n, column1                  
from #temp) aa 
where r_n_n >=@Count)
```

--> use your actual code here

--> increment the @count variable

```
set @count = @count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use loops or cursors, if you can avoid them. The devil of procedural thinking is pulling you away from the light of set based approaches deep into pain and misery!

> I know the column names in advance, I just did it to ease the way I would loop through each column

**NO!** This is not easing the way but punishing the poor engine :-)

Is it this you are looking for?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT, VAl1 DECIMAL(14,4), Val2 DECIMAL(14,4), Val3 DECIMAL(14,4));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(1,1,10,100),(2,2,20,200),(3,3,30,300);
GO
    SELECT AVG(Val1) AS Avg1,AVG(Val2) AS Avg2,AVG(Val3) AS Avg3
    FROM dbo.Test;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
```

The result

```
Avg1        Avg2        Avg3
2.000000    20.000000   200.000000
```

### UPDATE

If you just want to be lazy and avoid typing, you might try something like this:

```
SELECT ',AVG(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('AVG_' + COLUMN_NAME)   
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND TABLE_NAME='Test'
FOR XML PATH('')
```

The result

```
,AVG(ID) AS [AVG_ID],AVG(VAl1) AS [AVG_VAl1],AVG(Val2) AS [AVG_Val2],AVG(Val3) AS [AVG_Val3]
```

With this trick you can build your *hard coded* statement quite easily :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.. I have two tables (they have the same rows and columns) but one with stock returns and the other with the respective quintiles of each return. I made a left join to calculate the average of the returns based on the top quintile that's why I am looking for a function that could go through each column an calculate the average

Comment: @RobinhoHcp This is a perfect example why you should read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)